# how to get click count outside of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

hi here is the code i am playing with

```
//define a function
var test=function() {

 var v=0;
 var counter=0;
  // click on the element id=z2
 $('#z2').click(function(){

  v = ++counter;
   //call function testdata 
  testdata();

  })

  function testdata() {

   return v;

   } // end of testdata

   } // end of  var test

     //calling p outside of the scope of var test.
    var p =test.testdata();
```

now p should return the value of v but it is showing undefined in console.log.

any suggestions please

Comment: You have lines of text in your code that are uncommented. I'm not sure if this is the original but please format it properly.

Comment: Can you please brief out your exact requirement, may be it can be achieved in some other way.

Comment: my main aim is to paginate table data. i display 10 records at a time with a graph.the user clicks (#z2) and hence more 10 records are displayed, till we reach the end of the recordcount. than we do that in reverse. hence the need to catch the value of clicks. i pass a lot of parameters to display the table and graph, along with the number of clicks. due to closure all the values are the same for the next large item from the table. hence the need to catch the click count. i can upload more code if needed. i am stumped. the suggested solution is inadequate. $.click() does not return values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your code isn't working is because `testdata` only exists within the scope of the function `test` (making it a private function) - calling it within `test` will work, but at far as the rest of your code is concerned, it doesn't exist.

One way of making this work is to use `test` as a constructor, keeping the variables private but making the function public, like so:

```
// define constructor
var Test = function() {

    // private
    var v = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var that = this;

    // click on the element id=z2
    $('#z2').click(function(){
        v = ++counter;
        //call function testdata 
        that.testdata();
    });

    // public
    this.testdata = function() {
        return v;
    }
}

var p = new Test();
p.testdata(); // works!
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/fissioncat/tg84mbwp/4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to define v as an int like so

```
var v = 0;
```

Also that function will return undefined since that function only returns its argument which is undefined

I have a hard time understanding your problem however this is what I would have done:

```
//define a function
var test = function() {

    var v = 0;
    var counter=0;
    // click on the element id=z2
    $('#z2').click(function(){
        v = ++counter;
        return v;
    })
} // end of  var test

var p = test();
```

Comment: thanx for catching my error. yes, the function returns undefined. but am i not passing the global variable v.which is visible inside. I want see the value of v outside. how can i get that please.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your code.

If you run it, it throws an error(1):
`test.testdata is not a function !`
If you look for test.testdata using a console, you will see it's **undefined** (error(2)).
If you try var p = testdata(), it also throws an error(3):
`testdata is undefined !`

You have defined function testdata **inside** function test. Any code also inside test can see
your function testdata, but any code **outside** test don't see it.
Your var p calling testdata is **outside**. That's why error(3).

With defining testdata inside test, you might have thought it get's automatically added to test as a property. That's not the case. You **can** add properties to a function, but that must happen outside this function. That's why error(1) and (2).

Let's try:

```
// declare your functions by name,
// you later can call them by name without need for a variable
function test() {
    // one variable is enough here
    var c = 0;
    $("#z2").click(function() {
        ++c;
        testdata();
    });
}
// function testdata declared by name outside function test
function testdata() {return c;}
// now we can attach testdata as a property to test
test.testdata = testdata;

var p = c; // should be 0 but is undefined
var p = testdata(); // no error, but undefined.
var p = test.testdata(); // no error, but undefined. Why?
```

The same problem as error(3), but now with variable **c**. It's declared **inside** test,
all code outside can't see it. (Look for keywords **scope** and **closure** to learn more);

We try again:

```
// declare var c outside, so it's in the global scope,
//all following code can see it.
var c = 0;
function test() {
    $("#z2").click(function() {
        ++c;
        testdata();
    });
}
function testdata() {return c;}
test.testdata = testdata;

var p = c; // --> 0
var p = testdata(); // --> 0
var p = test.testdata(); // --> 0
```

Okay, now get your click-function to work.

Comment: My username is Martin Ernst, new since three days. I forgot to login before answering, so it seems I created a new user. Does anybody know how to fix this? Many thanks.

Comment: @Martin Ernst: I've found the way to merge users together.